# Обработчик кнопки и final

Tags: android, button, edittext

При попытке получить значение из EditText и передать его в String, а затем вывести через Toast компилятор просит указать значения String (коих 2) через final. Но если я укажу их как final, это ведь значит, что они становятся константами. Так как мне настроить обработчик кнопки, чтобы он не просил указывать переменные как final

P.S
Сильно не ругайтесь:D

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText editTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_title);
        editTitle.getText();
        EditText editTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_title);
        editTitleText.getText();
        Button buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_add);


        String title = editTitleText.toString();

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, title //компилятор просит указать эту переменную как final, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: почему вам не нужно, чтобы они были final? Более того, сами по себе все переменные типа String и так константы, но вы ведь этого даже не замечали .. Это требования языка - любые "внешние" переменные, используемые в анонимном классе, должны быть final для безопасности операций с ними

Comment: @pavlofff я пытаюсь создать заметки. И эти 2 стринговых значения буду служить названием и текстом заметки. Разве я смогу их переопределить для создания последующей заметки, если они буду указаны как final?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что метод `onClick()` будет выполнен когда будет нажата кнопка.
Метод `onCreate()` на тот момент уже завершится и локальная переменная `title` уже не будет существовать.
Для того, чтобы такой код работал, компилятор создаст копию переменной в самом обработчике при его создании и, соответственно значение этой копии уже не изменится. И чтобы вы это понимали компилятор заставляет указать `final`.

Ваша ошибка в том, что вы хотите взять значение из `EditText` сразу в `onCreate()` - когда он ещё даже не появился на экране и, тем более в него ещё никто ничего не вписал (разве что вы сами в макете активности).
Правильнее будет это делать в обработчике:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText editTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_title);
        final EditText editTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text_title);
        Button buttonAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_add);

        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String title = editTitleText.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: То есть, если я хочу внести эти строки в бд, то мне нужно вызывать экземпляр класса бд в обработчике?

Comment: Грубо говоря да, но обычно всю работу с базой оформляют в отдельном классе и в обработчике делегируют задачу этому классу (то есть просто вызывается метод, который заносит данные в базу).

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете Анонимный класс в качестве слушателя, естественно он просит сделать final.
Способов решений два. 
 
Первое переписать через лямды(чтоб использовать лямды, градле нужно указать что используете java 1.8)
Второе это использовать имплементацию, для ваше активити делаете  implement OnClickListener
переопределяете метод onClick(View v) и в нем уже пишете обработчик кнопки

Answer (score 0):

Переопределите `onClick()`

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
            EditText editTitle;
            String title;
            EditText editTitleText;
            Button buttonAdd;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                editTitle =  findViewById(R.id.edit_title);
                editTitle.getText();
                editTitleText =  findViewById(R.id.edit_text_title);
                editTitleText.getText();
                buttonAdd = findViewById(R.id.button_add);
                title = editTitleText.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()){
                    case R.id.buttonAdd:
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, title,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```